# Distribution for strictly positive variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, lognormal-distribution

What are equivalents of the normal distribution when working with strictly positive quantities? That is the distributions that are:
 1. Mathematically convenient to work with
 2. The random variable is strictly positive
 3. The random variable models a sum of many small events

To add more precision to the last point: normal distribution arises naturally as the result of the central limit theorem - it is appropriate for modeling a sum of many small contributions. Now, suppose, I have a sum that is strictly positive - e.g., a sum of the molecules hitting a detector. From the mathematical viewpoint, the log-normal or gamma distributions would do the job... however from the point of view of the underlying phenomenon they are not applicable.

Comment: You seem to be searching for the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: My understanding is that the Poisson and the normal distributions are derived in different limits: e.g., if one starts from the binomial distribution for N trials, the Poisson corresponds to the number of successes n<<N, whereas for the normal n ~ N. More importantly, Poisson lacks many of the conveniences of working with a continuous distribution.

Comment: I believe there's a theorem that states any stable continuous distribution must have a mean of zero, implying there's nothing that meets all your criteria.  I cannot fathom, though, why you would reject use of a discrete distribution when analyzing discrete data like "[count] of the molecules hitting a detector."

Comment: Your point about stable distributions sounds interesting. Thanks! I didn't mean discrete data though, but rather continuous data which are often a sum of discrete events, but with insufficient resolution. Chemical quantities are a good example, although the detector was mentioned in the context of intensity measured by mass spectroscopy.